# Problems with plugin/installer manager in QGIS 2.6.1 Debian

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, error

An error has occured while executing Python code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/pyplugin_installer/installer_data.py", line 460, in xmlDownloaded
    if isCompatible(QGis.QGIS_VERSION, qgisMinimumVersion, qgisMaximumVersion):
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/pyplugin_installer/version_compare.py", line 188, in isCompatible
    if len(maxVer)TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Python version:
2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:41) 
[GCC 4.8.2]

When trying to open the plugin manages on Qgis 2.6.1 I get the following error:

QGIS version:
2.6.1-Brighton Brighton, exported

Python path: ['/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing', '/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/joseph/.qgis2/python', u'/home/joseph/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools']
```

Comment: I'm busy fixing this and pushing through a fix. Can you confirm how you realised it is InaSAFE causing the problem? I don't see InaSAFE referenced in any of the listings above.

Comment: A new build has been pushed up so this is fixed now

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by a plugin, inasafe, in the QGIS Python Plugins Repository that has a maximum version of 2.999.9999 which causes the error enountered.

The entry for the latest version of InaSAFE - 2.2.2 - has an invalid QGIS MAximum Version. Perhaps setting it to 2.99 as previously would be the thing to do.

Comment: Should be fixed now with INASAFE version 2.2.3: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/inasafe/version/2.2.3. The Maxversion is back to normal for the INASAFE plugin.

Answer (score 2):

if you go to https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=2.6
you will see the version error.

I am facing this problem as well. However, I can't find many users report about this problem, so I think it should be the computer setting problem ?

[image]